# Syntax error when trying to redirect the output of my python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, export-to-text

'Trying to redirect the output of my python script:

```
print('Hi')
python /path/to/script/script.py > /path/to/output/myfile.txt
```

However I am being told that '/' before path/to/output/myfile.txt is a syntax error

(I'm doing coursework and I need to export all my print statements into a .txt file)

(also some of my print statements are in For loops)

Comment: What error are you getting *exactly*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that the '/' before path/to/output/myfile.txt is a syntax error

Comment: Is your `python ...` command in some kind of shell? In your question you've put it right after `print(...)` as if it is a line of Python code. What kind of shell are you using? What **exactly** was the error that you got?

Comment: You should *provide the full error traceback*

Comment: Do you type these two lines in bash or python file?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga there is no error traceback, the code doesn't run a notification pops up to say syntax error and the '/' is highlighted

Comment: @Michal in a python file

Comment: Are you using IDLE? Wait, you've written `python /path/to/script/script.py > /path/to/output/myfile.txt` *inside* the Python script? Well, then that makes sense because that *isnt python* that is a bash pipe.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes I'm using IDLE, what should I do instead?

Comment: @HannahRowley Python is NOT bash, the redirection should be invocated during with execution, so the correct way is (in bash): `python myscript > output_file.txt`

Comment: Use that command in a bash shell?

Comment: @Michal  What's a bash shell.......

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What's a bash shell ........

Comment: Are you on windows, mac or linux?

Comment: I'm quite confused I just need to export data from a population model for my coursework, but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: @Michal Windows

Comment: It is a [unix shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-a-shell_003f.html#What-is-a-shell_003f) which you might use if you were on Linux or Mac. I had assumed you were using a shell since you were trying to use a bash command. I believe that commmand is the same in windows `cmd`. Alternatively,  use the `print("my string", file="/path/to/output/myfile.txt")` in your `print` statements in your script.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: If I use    print("my string", file="/path/to/output/myfile.txt")  then I get the error trace back:                                                                                       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hannah/Desktop/script.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("my string", file="/path/to/output/script.txt")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Whoops. that's my bad. You need to pass a file-object instead of a string. so something like `f = open('/path/to/output/myfile.txt', 'w'); print("mystring", file=f)` Alternatively, you could use `import sys; sys.stdout = open('/path/to/output/myfile.txt', "w")` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 1):

Python file is not bash interpreter, so you have to type you wnat to use output file as stdout in bash/cmd.

**EDIT**: As you are using windows, type this in your cmd.exe (Start -> Run -> cmd.exe)

`python /path/to/script/script.py > /path/to/output/myfile.txt`

Comment: @Hannah Rowley If you found my answer to be correct, please, tick it with the ok mark under voting arrows.